# Find .nextsibling with Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get (some) contents of a table from an URL.
So far I have managed to get two desired contents of the page, but there is a third one (third column) that I would like to get only its text. The problem is, the underlying link exists elsewhere on the page (with different text) and if I want to load the table into an SQL database, the contents of the third colum won't match the first two columns.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4
startURL = "http://some.url/website.html"
page = urllib2.urlopen(startURL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
for links in soup.findAll("a"):
    if "href" in links.attrs:
        www = links.attrs.values()
        if not "https://" in www[0]:  # to exclude all non-relative links, e.g. external links
            if "view/" in www[0]: # To get only my desired links of column 1
                link_of_column1 = www[0]   # this is now my wanted link
```

Okay, so with this code I can get the second column. Where and how would I have to apply the .nextsibling() function, to get the next link in the next (3rd) column?

Edit:
As I have been asked: The URL is https://myip.ms/browse/web_hosting/World_Web_Hosting_Global_Statistics.html and I want to get the contents from Column 2 and 3, which is "Hosting Company" (link-text and link) and "Country" (only the text).

Edit2:
Another thing I forgot...how can I extract the information that its `137,157 records`?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: I want to extract the coloumns "Hosting Company" (text and link), Country (only text) from https://myip.ms/browse/web_hosting/World_Web_Hosting_Global_Statistics.html. So actually only 2 columns, but 3 types of information.

Answer (score 1):

First find the table which has all the info using its `id=web_hosting_tbl` attribute. Then iterate over all the rows of the table. But, if you look at the page source, the rows you need are not consecutive, but, alternate, and they don't have any class names. Also, the first row of the table is the header row, so we've to skip that.

After getting the required rows (using `table.find_all('tr')[1::2]`), find all the columns and then get the required information from the corresponding columns.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://myip.ms/browse/web_hosting/World_Web_Hosting_Global_Statistics.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', id='web_hosting_tbl')
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1::2]:
    all_columns = row.find_all('td')
    name = all_columns[1].a.text
    link = all_columns[1].a['href']
    country = all_columns[2].a.text
    print(name, link, country, sep=' | ')
```

**Partial output:**

```
Godaddy.com, LLC | /view/web_hosting/2433/Godaddy_com_LLC.html | USA
Cloudflare, Inc | /view/web_hosting/4638/Cloudflare_Inc.html | USA
Amazon.com, Inc | /view/web_hosting/615/Amazon_com_Inc.html | USA
Ovh Sas | /view/web_hosting/7593/Ovh_Sas.html | France
Hetzner Online Ag | /view/web_hosting/45081/Hetzner_Online_Ag.html | Germany
Hostgator.com Llc | /view/web_hosting/26757/Hostgator_com_Llc.html | USA
Google Inc | /view/web_hosting/617/Google_Inc.html | USA
Bluehost Inc | /view/web_hosting/3886/Bluehost_Inc.html | USA
...
```

Comment: That is awesome, thanks! You know, I had found that table "web_hosting_tbl" and tried to parse it but I kept getting an error. Why? Because i was using the code $soup.find("table", {"id":"web_hosting_tbl")$ which is in the book that I am using to learn. That book however is written for Python 3 while I am using 2.7. I had not gotten the idea that the syntax might be different there and just assumed there is a mistake in my code, but now I know it's just a version matter. So thanks a lot, your code is extremely useful for my further project!

Comment: @Khaled, actually `soup.find("table", {"id":"web_hosting_tbl"})` is a valid format too.

Comment: I see, then who knows what else was the problem, I couldn't find it. But your code works beautifully now, except that the $sep = " | "$ doesn't seem to work in Python 2.7, but that's okay, I am going to shove all the data into an SQL database anyway :)

Comment: You can use `html.parser` here too. To install `lxml` just do `pip install lxml`. And yeah, that `sep=' | '` was used just to show the output in some good looking format here.

Comment: Well, I do not really care whether I use $html.parser$ or $lxml$, as long as it works :) One more question that I forgot...how can I get the information out that its `137,175 records`?

Answer (score 1):

**Code: (Python 3.6+, used [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/))**

```
import urllib.parse
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime

import bs4
import requests

HostingCompany = namedtuple('HostingCompany',
                            ('name', 'country', 'websites', 'usage', 'usage_by_top', 'update_time'))


class MyIpLink:
    url_base = 'https://myip.ms'

    def __init__(self, tag: bs4.element.Tag, *, is_anchor=False):
        a_tag = tag.find('a')

        if is_anchor:  # treat `tag` as an anchor tag
            a_tag = tag

        self.text = tag.text.strip()
        self.url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.url_base, a_tag['href'])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(text={repr(self.text)}, url={repr(self.url)})'


url = 'https://myip.ms/browse/web_hosting/World_Web_Hosting_Global_Statistics.html'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.select('#web_hosting_tbl > tbody > tr')[::2]  # skips "more info" rows
companies = []

for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_all('td')

    name = MyIpLink(tds[1])
    country = MyIpLink(tds[2])
    websites = [MyIpLink(a, is_anchor=True) for a in tds[3].find_all('a')]
    usage = MyIpLink(tds[4])
    usage_by_top = MyIpLink(tds[5])
    update_time = datetime.strptime(tds[6].text.strip(), '%d %b %Y, %H:%M')

    company = HostingCompany(name, country, websites, usage, usage_by_top, update_time)
    companies.append(company)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(companies)

print(companies[0].name.text)
print(companies[0].name.url)
print(companies[0].country.text)
```

**Output:**

```
[HostingCompany(name=MyIpLink(text='Godaddy.com, LLC', url='https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/2433/Godaddy_com_LLC.html'), country=MyIpLink(text='USA', url='https://myip.ms/view/best_hosting/USA/Best_Hosting_in_USA.html'), websites=[MyIpLink(text='www.godaddy.com', url='https://myip.ms/go.php?1229687315_ITg7Im93dCkWE0kNAhQSEh0FUeHq5Q==')], usage=MyIpLink(text='512,701 sites', url='https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/ownerID/2433/ownerIDii/2433'), usage_by_top=MyIpLink(text='951 sites', url='https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/rankii/100000/ownerID/2433/ownerIDii/2433'), update_time=datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 2, 5, 17)),
 HostingCompany(name=MyIpLink(text='Cloudflare, Inc', url='https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/4638/Cloudflare_Inc.html'), country=MyIpLink(text='USA', url='https://myip.ms/view/best_hosting/USA/Best_Hosting_in_USA.html'), websites=[MyIpLink(text='www.cloudflare.com', url='https://myip.ms/go.php?840626136_OiEsK2ROSxAdGl4QGhYJG+Tp6fnrv/f49w==')], usage=MyIpLink(text='488,119 sites', url='https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/ownerID/4638/ownerIDii/4638'), usage_by_top=MyIpLink(text='16,160 sites', url='https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/rankii/100000/ownerID/4638/ownerIDii/4638'), update_time=datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 2, 5, 10)),
 HostingCompany(name=MyIpLink(text='Amazon.com, Inc', url='https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/615/Amazon_com_Inc.html'), country=MyIpLink(text='USA', url='https://myip.ms/view/best_hosting/USA/Best_Hosting_in_USA.html'), websites=[MyIpLink(text='www.amazonaws.com', url='https://myip.ms/go.php?990446041_JyYhKGFxThMQHUMRHhcDExHj8vul7f75')], usage=MyIpLink(text='453,230 sites', url='https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/ownerID/615/ownerIDii/615'), usage_by_top=MyIpLink(text='9,557 sites', url='https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/rankii/100000/ownerID/615/ownerIDii/615'), update_time=datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 2, 5, 4)),
 ...
]

Godaddy.com, LLC
https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/2433/Godaddy_com_LLC.html
USA
```

Gonna update the answer with some explanation in the evening. Cheers!

Comment: Your code is a perfect example that even something programmatically simple, can be done in a very complicated way :) Your code shows me that I am still in the early stages of Python unfortunately :D

Comment: Lol, is it the compliment or the exact opposite? 

Comment: Oh, I get it :) You're on the right track, just don't give up. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach. It should give you the texts from `column 2`, the links from `column 2` and again the texts from `column 3` out of that table. I used `lxml` instead of `BeautifulSoup` to make it faster. Thanks.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from lxml.html import fromstring

URL = 'https://myip.ms/browse/web_hosting/World_Web_Hosting_Global_Statistics.html'

res = requests.get(URL)
root = fromstring(res.text)

for items in root.cssselect('#web_hosting_tbl tr:not(.expand-child)')[1:]:
    name = items.cssselect("td.row_name a")[0].text
    link = urljoin(URL,items.cssselect("td.row_name a")[0].attrib['href'])
    country = items.cssselect("td a[href^='/view/best_hosting/']")[0].text
    print(name, link, country)
```

Results:

```
Godaddy.com, LLC https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/2433/Godaddy_com_LLC.html USA
Cloudflare, Inc https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/4638/Cloudflare_Inc.html USA
Amazon.com, Inc https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/615/Amazon_com_Inc.html USA
Ovh Sas https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/7593/Ovh_Sas.html France
Hetzner Online Ag https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/45081/Hetzner_Online_Ag.html Germany
Hostgator.com Llc https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/26757/Hostgator_com_Llc.html USA
Google Inc https://myip.ms/view/web_hosting/617/Google_Inc.html USA
```

Comment: Also a nice solution certainly, but I have no experience with those modules you are using, so unfortunately I cannot really follow it (yet) :-/